# Ring of regular functions of $Sl_n$ (as a linear algebraic group over a field).

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-groups

Is there a nice, more *hands-on*, way to interpret the ring
$$\mathcal{O}(Sl_n(k))\simeq\frac{k[X_{i,j}:1\leq i,j\leq n]}{(\det(X_{i,j})-1)},$$
where $k$ is a field?

Comment: I don't know about hands on, but this ring can be seen as the "generic determinant $1$ matrix", in the sense that if you call it $R$, then for any $k$-algebra $S$, $\hom_k(R,S) \simeq SL_n(S)$ where $\hom_k$ denotes $k$-algebra morphisms

Comment: Mmm, I think I understand what you mean. Very cool! But what do you mean by $\text{hom}_k(R,S)\simeq Sl_n(S)$ precisely? They are isomorphic as what?

Comment: More precisely, the two functors $\hom_k(R,-)$ and $SL_n(-)$ are isomorphic. This actually tells you that you have a natural *group* structure on $\hom_k(R,S)$ for any $S$, and they're isomorphic as groups then

Comment: Think of the $X_{ij}$ as the function that takes a matrix to it's i,j coordinate.